# Automate Removal Of Boundary's with CSV - Remove-CMBoundary

Tags: powershell, sccm, boundary

`CSV.csv`:

```
Name,Type,Value,Name,Subnet
Manchester, IPSubnet,192.168.1.0,Manchester,192.168.1.0
```

I'm trying to automate the removal of boundaries from a site (I'm adding them in as IPA address range boundaries on a new primary as part of this process.

The `Remove-CMBoundary` cmdlet seems to require an ID, I don't have that ID in my CSV, so I'm trying to pull it from SCCM as part of the removal process.

Note: There are multiple boundaries in the existing groups which need to stay where they are and, only 3 boundaries need to be removed per group so, slightly more tricky.

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\NETS\csv.csv"
foreach ($line in $csv) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Removing boundary for $($line.Subnet)"
    Remove-CMBoundary -Name $line.$Name -Type IPSubnet -Value $line.Subnet
}
```

The above doesn't work because you need the Boundary Id - not just the subnet information. Subsequent digging got me here:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\csv.csv"
foreach ($line in $csv) {
    Get-CMBoundary -BoundaryName $csv.Name |
        select Value,BoundaryID |
        Export-Csv C:\Boundary.csv
    $boundaryids = Import-Csv C:\Boundary.csv
    foreach ($id in $boundaryids) {
        Where-Object -eq $line.'Subnet'
    } Remove-CMBoundary -Id $id.'boundaryID'
}
```

I bet this is way too much effort for what I'm actually trying to do. Can anyone see where I'm trying to take this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with SCCM, but judging from your code sample you're probably trying to do something like this:

```
foreach ($line in $csv) {
    Get-CMBoundary -BoundaryName $line.Name | Where-Object {
        $_.Value -eq $line.Subnet
    } | ForEach-Object {
        Remove-CMBoundary -Id $_.BoundaryID
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know SCCM either, but

- according to [Remove-CMBoundary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/system-center/powershell/system-center-2012-r2/jj821894(v=sc.20)) it accepts piped input
- and has a `-WhatIf` parameter.

So this should do:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\csv.csv"
ForEach ($line in $csv) {
    Get-CMBoundary -BoundaryName $line.Name | 
        Where-Object Value -eq $line.Subnet |
            Remove-CMBoundary -WhatIf
}
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf` (or alternatively use `-Confirm`)

**EDIT this way your try from the comment might work**

```
$Site = "ABC" 
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\csv.csv" 
ForEach ($line in $csv) { 
    Get-CMBoundary -BoundaryName $line.Name | 
        Where-Object{($_.Value -eq $line.Subnet) -and 
                     ($_.ShortCode -eq $Site) } |
            Remove-CMBoundary
}
```

Comment: To enumerate only 1 site in the CSV at a time, I unsuccessfully tried this:$Site = "ABC" $csv = Import-Csv "C:\csv.csv"
foreach ($line in $csv) { 
                        
                        Get-CMBoundary -BoundaryName $line.Name | Where-Object {
                        $_.Value -eq $line.Subnet -and $_.ShortCode -eq $Site
    } | ForEach-Object {
        Remove-CMBoundary -Id $_.BoundaryID }

Comment: Pipeline error there - input object cannot be bound to any parameters - I upvoted it too early

Comment: Your try from the comment follows Ansgars template, not mine - so no reason to complain here. IMO you should enclose the two where conditions in parentheses before -anding them. See changed answer. After my edit you could retract your up vote - but why?

Comment: Much appreciate your input and edit, won't retract anything, just note to self, should test before upvoting to make sure things do work on others code

Comment: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Id'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Comment: My bad, when piped the -ID parameter isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the original query, to enumerate a site at a time, one would do this:

```
$Site = "ABC"
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\csv.csv"
foreach ($line in $csv) { 

                        Get-CMBoundary -BoundaryName $line.Name | Where-Object {
                        $_.Value -eq $line.Subnet -and $_.ShortCode -eq $line.$Site} | 
        ForEach-Object {
        Remove-CMBoundary -Id $_.BoundaryID 
} 
    }
```